# Innodb engine doesn't support full-text indexing.How can I do text search?

Tags: php, mysql, search, full-text-search, innodb

I am using  Innodb engine  for its foreign key constraint and  transaction  features in mysql.I want to do a full-text search , and that is not supported  with innoDB tables. I'm not willing to move to MyISAM tables.and mysql version is lesser than 5.6.Any Suggestion how can i do  text search with good performance and speed ? Thank you.

Comment: Lucene? Sphinx? Solr? Xapian?

Comment: I think only starting from MySQL 5.6 , InnoDB supports  full-text indexing .

Comment: In fact, `full-text` search is available since `MySQL 5.5` as shown in the [mysql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html)

Answer (score 1):

**From MySQL 5.6 Reference Manual**

MySQL has support for `full-text indexing` and searching:

A full-text index in MySQL is an index of type FULLTEXT.

Full-text indexes can be used only with `InnoDB` or `MyISAM` tables, and can be created only for CHAR, VARCHAR, or TEXT columns.